# Extend "pimp my Iterable" to Options

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterable

Recently I have found in my code several places where I was first gathering some solutions, and then continued processing them only if the solution was unique (solution collection contained only one element). Following code is an attempt to solve this in a more functional manner.

```
  implicit class GetOnlyOne[A](val coll: Iterable[A]) {
    def getonlyone = {
      if (coll.isEmpty) None
      else if (coll.tail.isEmpty) coll.headOption
      else None
    }
  }
```

The function can be used like:

```
Seq(1).getonlyone
Seq(1,2).getonlyone
Set(1).getonlyone
```

What currently does not work is:

```
Some(1).getonlyone
```

Could the function be improved to accept `Option` as well, besides of `Iterable`s, perhaps with view bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to bodge something for `Option` with view bounds, but the general solution is to define a typeclass: you define an interface and provide an implicit instance of that interface for each type you want to support:

```
trait CanGetOnlyOne[F[_]] {
  def getOnlyOne[A](fa: F[A]): Option[A]
}
object CanGetOnlyOne {
  implicit object CanGetOnlyOneIterable extends CanGetOnlyOne[Iterable]{
    def getOnlyOne[A](fa: Iterable[A]) = ...
  }
  implicit object CanGetOnlyOneOption extends CanGetOnlyOne[Option] {
    def getOnlyOne[A](fa: Option[A]) = fa
  }
}
implicit class GetOnlyOne[F[_], A](fa: F[A])(implicit cgoo: CanGetOnlyOne[F]) {
  def getonlyone = cgoo.getOnlyOne(fa)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Option` can be implicitly converted to an `Iterable`, so the following works:

```
implicit class GetOnlyOne[A, Coll](coll: Coll)
                                  (implicit view: Coll => Iterable[A]) {
  def getonlyone = {
    val it: Iterable[A] = coll
    if (it.isEmpty) None
    else if (it.tail.isEmpty) it.headOption
    else None
  }
}
```

However for `Option` is this very inefficient, because your `getonlyone` is essentially the `identity` function. Therefore, I would just introduce a second method extension just for options:

```
implicit class GetOnlyOneOption[A](private val opt: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def getonlyone = opt
}
```